# Is there a Design Pattern for separating preparation of work from execution?

Tags: design-patterns

Is there a Design Pattern which separates the preparation of work from its execution?

Some examples:

- Databases execute queries by creating a query plan and executing it.
- For my application, I implemented a staged approach for copying files so I could show a progress bar. I first create a list of file copy actions and then loop through the list updating the progress bar based on the weight (file size) of each action.
- I also implemented a staged approach to fetch data where I prepare a list of batches and then execute them. The reasons were to reduce complexity (different batches have different parameters) and to prevent memory overload (there is a maximum amount of data fetched by a batch).

The basic pattern is that there is a 'Planner' object which breaks down a task into 'Work Items' that can be executed individually.

I'm just curious and I hope that an already known Design Pattern can help in communicating with other developers and perhaps give me some ideas to improve my design.

Comment: I personally call it the "Execution Plan" pattern. I find it helpful for abstracting side-effects for unit-testable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said

"The basic pattern is that there is a 'Planner' object which breaks down a task into 'Work Items' that can be executed individually."

This indicates that you might want something like the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).  A simple implementation involved just defining an Interface, "Command" with a single method, and creating subclasses.  I really like this pattern because it is easy to implement, and the commands are really easy to test in isolation.

You also might want to look at the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).  If applicable, you could make a CompositeCommand abstract class.  This provides a clean way to execute all the commands that compose a task.  Also, its really easy to implement.

Your "Planner" object would create the composite command (or just a list of commands if you dont want to use composite) that satisfies the job...

Comment: The Command pattern encapsulates a request to an object and doesn't specify how the request is executed. A 'Work Item' represents an actual implementation of some sort. I like the CompositeCommand idea.

Comment: @martijn, the canonical command has an "execute" method.  I think you are implying that they don't do work; I don't agree with that at all.  The command pattern in essence is a way to capture an operation and execute it at a time of your choosing.

Comment: @hvgotcodes In the Participants section of Command in Gamma, it says that a ConcreteCommand defines a binding between a Receiver object and an action. The Receiver object knows how to perform the operations associated with the action. So, in the classic implementation of Command, a ConcreteCommand implements Execute() by calling a method on the Receiver. This means that ConcreteCommand does not do any 'real' work. In general, 'Command' does not feel like the right pattern, because it has something to do with communicating between objects, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @hvgotcodes BTW, I was wrong in my first comment - the ConcreteCommand does specify how the request is executed (by calling a method on Receiver), however, it does not implement it.

Comment: @Martijn, thats true.  Note that 2 pages later it says "At one extreme it merely defines a binding...at the other extreme it implements everything itself without delegating to a receiver at all..."  The point is, using an interface with a single method called 'Execute' will achieve what you want.  One pattern that has that structure is the Command Pattern.

Comment: @hvgotcodes Ah, I didn't remember that part. I suppose in that case, my 'work item' could be considered a Command. I always implemented Command in a more abstract fashion. Thanks!

Comment: @Martijn, yeah no worries.  I think the key to these types of things is not to get too bogged down in the pendantics of these types of things.  You want to do it right, but you don't want to overdesign it.  you know what i mean?

Answer (score 1):

In distributed systems you often see a broker or scheduler allocating work to workers or agents; the scheduler might be implemented with some knowledge of the workload, and be able to split it up, or might just manage allocating tasks from a queue to workers.

I've yet to find a shared description or name for this pattern -- but take a look here for a starting point: [Master-Worker pattern in distributed computing](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365083/Distributed-Computing-Made-Easy).

Comment: I think Master-Worker is an extension of what I was looking for, but it's an interesting pattern. Thanks!

Comment: Np .. interesting question, I think there's actually a whole family of stuff in here with subtle variations.